# Refused to load the script 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'

Tags: google-chrome, content-security-policy

I continue to get an error stating "Refused to load the script 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' xxxxxxxxxxxxx" Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback."  I got the same error when disabling Chrome security via the command chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security.  I did see the google developer guide states to use nonce in reCAPTCHA api script tag.  I suspect a server has the policy.  How do I get the nonce value?  Why can I not disable Chrome security to test my code?  I am using an asp.net mvc website.  I have also tried a meta tag in the view unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is to add [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) or https://www.google.com to your script-src directive. Currently it refuses to load the initial script.

You generate a random value for the nonce. Seems like you need to insert it into the script tag. You also have to insert it into your CSP.